# Operate on BlueZ provided file descriptor in C

Tags: python, c, linux, bluetooth, bluez

I am attempting to work with the `org.bluez.Profile1` in `BlueZ 5.44`. When connecting with a new device via the `NewConnection` DBus method, we get a file descriptor to work with. I am fairly confused on what state this file descriptor is in, and what I need to do in order to read/write from it. Simply calling `read`/`write` does not behave as expected for me.

In the file [test/test-profile](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-profile?h=5.44), I see this line of python code:

```
self.fd = fd.take()
```

I am struggling to find the Linux C equivalent to the `take` method. Any advice on how to configure this fd in C code so I can read/write with the fd would be very helpful!

Thanks

Comment: If I remember well, BlueZ uses the socket abstraction, so I would say that the file descriptor is the opened socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue ended up being with the `gdbus-codegen` tool I was using. When using that tool, each fd parameter is actually an index to a `GUnixFDList` (documentation on that object [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GUnixFDList.html)). In order to have the `GUnixFDList` passed with the method `NewConnection`, I had to annotate the method in xml as `org.gtk.GDBus.C.UnixFD`. Annotation documentation can be found [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-codegen.html).